# Getting The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. while running start-process

Tags: powershell

Can you please help what I am doing wrong. I am getting The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect error while running below code. I tried calling install.bat file directly but no luck still getting same error.

I checked the command running manually it is working.

```
Try
{
    $product = "Oracle"
    $installed = Get-Application($product)
#   """$($toolsDir)\$AppFolder\install.bat"""
    
    ## Variable: Oracle client
    $oclient = @(
    "/c"
    """D:\Working_Area\TS-60602_GDCE-16718\scb.oracle_client.install\tools\ODAC193Xcopy_32bit\install.bat"""
    "all"
    """D:\app\client\dcap-admin\product\19.3.0"""
    "odac"
    )
    
     "Check Oracle Client 19 is already installed."
    $oclient
    
    if (-not ($installed))
    {
     "Found application Oracle Client 19 is not installed. Preparing to install the application. Please wait..."
    Push-Location $toolsDir\$AppFolder
    #$binary
    #$config
    [int]$result = (Start-Process "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList $oclient -NoNewWindow -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
        
    if ($result -eq '0' -or $result -eq '3010' -or $result -eq '1641')
    {   
     "Oracle Client 19 installed sucessfully $($result)."
    Push-Location $toolsDir
    } Else {
    Throw ("Oracle Client 19 installation failed with ERROR: $($result).")
    }
    } Else {
     "Found application Oracle Client 19 is already installed. Skipping the installation and exiting the process." 
    Exit 0
    
    }   
} catch {   
     "$($_.Exception.Message). Refer log $logfile for more information."
    Exit $lastexitcode = $result
}
```

Comment: You need to use either Run As or credentials.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3